# why won't my program accept int[] parameter in method when called in main?

Tags: java, arrays, program-entry-point

for some reason when I try and add an integer array as the parameter of this method when I call it in my main method, it doesn't recognise the parameter as an array or something, I'm not sure why it does this. I call the array like this: has23([2,4]).

```
public static boolean has23(int[] n) {

        Boolean correct = null;

        while ((n.length == 2)) {
            for (int i : n) {
                Arrays.asList(n);
                if (Arrays.asList(n).contains(2) || Arrays.asList(n).contains(3)) {
                    correct = true;

                }
                else;
                correct = false;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(correct);
        return correct;

    }
```

Comment: That is Python Syntax. Java is: `has23(new int[]{2,4]})`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because

```
has23([2, 4])
```

is not legal Java syntax. You can do

```
has23(new int[] { 2, 4 })
```

instead. Or

```
int[] arr = { 2, 4 };
has23(arr);
```

**but** not

```
has23({2, 4});
```